# How to Auto Increment Multiple columns in OSClass table

Tags: php, mysql, osclass

I am able to insert value using this code

```
$this->dao->insert(
    $this->getTableName(), 
    array(
        "s_name" => $name, 
        "e_type" =>$type, 
        "b_required" => $required, 
        "s_slug" => $slug, 
        's_options' => $options,
    )
);
$id = $this->dao->insertedId();
```

But I want to update `order` field same time after inserting new values.

My `oc_t_meta_fields` table structure

```
pk_i_id    order    s_name   e_type    b_required     s_slug      s_options

1            1          one   text         0              0           0
2            2          two   text         0              0           0
```

Thank you for your time. I am new on osclass. Help me is possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_. It's not at all clear what you're asking above, can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: why? what is the point of having the table two identical values. if you have one ai field the other will always be exactly the same...